# Finding the point in time where two objects collide

Tags: vectors

Suppose you have two boats $A$ and $B$ both travelling at a constant velocity; let's say $A$ travels at a velocity of $(-\mathbf{i}+6\mathbf{j})$ m/s, and $B$ at $(3\mathbf{i}+4\mathbf{j})$ m/s, and when $t=0$, boat $A$ has position vector of $(2\mathbf{i}-10\mathbf{j})$ m, and boat $B$ has a position vector of $(-26\mathbf{i}+4\mathbf{j})$ m. Is there a method to find the *time* at which these boats will collide?

Comment: Write their positions as a function of time, set their positions equal to each other, then solve the resulting equation(s) for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x_A=2-t $$
$$y_A=-10+6t $$

$$x_B=-26+3t $$
$$y_B=4+4t $$

They collide when $x_A=x_B $

or
$$2-t=-26+3t \implies \color {red}{t=7 s}$$

if we plugg it into $y_A$, we get

$$y_A=-10+42=32=y_B $$They will meet each other at the point
$$(-5 ,32)$$

Comment: Ah okay, but how come 2-t=-26+3t?

Comment: @BarryBBenson Same position = same coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$\vec{s}_t=\vec{s}_0+t\vec{v}$$

You should be able to find locations of both boats at any moment $t$ and solve for collision time.

Comment: So I should do a simultaneous equation in which I find both t and s0?

Comment: You mean $t$ and $s_t$.

Comment: Yeah, so I should make a simultaneous equation?

Comment: write down an expression for position of $A$ at time $t$, another expression for position of $B$ at time $t$, they collide when the position at time $t$ is equal.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

the motion of $A$ is given by:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_A\\y_A
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\6
\end{pmatrix}t+\begin{pmatrix}
2\\-10
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the motion of $B$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_B\\y_B
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\4
\end{pmatrix}t+\begin{pmatrix}
-26\\4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and they collide if there is a time $t$ such that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_A\\y_A
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_B\\y_B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the time to collision is the same or constant, after finding length 
from orgin by radial distances $L_1,L_2 $ of position vector length

we should have

$$ t = \frac{L_1}{v_1}=\frac{L_2}{v_2} $$